# How to accelerate Django mysql queries to show in datatables?

Tags: python, django, datatables

I am developing a website with Django and i have about 500 object for now. It takes page 2 seconds to load and display in datatables. I show 10 objects with 50 pages in jquery datatables. However, the data may get bigger as the time goes by. What should i do to prevent website crushing or not loading at all. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend you paginate your results if you expect your dataset to grow in the future. You don't want to be sending MBs of data to the client every time they reload their page.

1. Enable server-side rendering on DataTables ([see more](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)).
2. Modify the *ajax* attribute for your DataTable class instantiation to include the necessary parameters such as page number ([see more](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax)).
3. Implement pagination on DRF ([see more](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/)).